# Connecting to signals of private widgets

Tags: qt

Witht QtCreator set up as default when you create a widget the class for it creates the form as private to the class. So you have for example something like this:

```
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

//...

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
```

Now what I want to know is how you connect to the signals within the `ui`. For example if this widget was embedded into a QStackedWidget and when a button is pressed the page displayed needs to change. I would have considered connecting to the button but `ui` is private so I cannot.

Do I have to create signals in `MainWindow` and then within that connect the 'ui' signals to them and thus bubble up the hierarchy? Or have I missed something simple?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have an unrelated object connect to signals/slots of aggregate components, even if you could it would break encapsulation and become a maintenance nightmare.

You need to expose the signals/slots of the aggregate components by adding them to the `MainWindow` API, and then call the relative `ui` component method in the definition.

For example, in the `MainWindow` definition, add:

```
signals:
    void buttonClicked();
```

And then in constructor, do:

```
connect( ui->button, SIGNAL( clicked() ), this, SIGNAL( buttonClicked() ) );
```

This way, your `MainWindow` class propagates signals from it's aggregates - but finetuned to exactly how you intend the class to be used.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had picked up that it would be a nightmare to maintain which is why I am trying to get it right so going forward I learn the best processes :-) So if I have understood you correctly what you mean is that in my aggregate component I would need to create signals that represent, say, the button click and then my `MainWindow` would connect to that signal then within the aggreagate component its just a case of connecting the signals together?

Comment: @Firedragon I've edited my answer to add an example.  For slots, add your slot to the header, and then in it's definition call the aggregate component directly (you can't chain slots together in a `connect()` call).